# How to remove babel-loader from React application?

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill, webpack-3.6

I want to remove babel-loader from my React application.

I'm trying to do is completely remove Babel from my project but I'm facing these issues:

```
ERROR in ./index.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:4) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
```

Comment: If you remove Babel, what's going to be doing any transpilation that's needed? Or are you writing source code such that it's not needed at all? What _is_ the unexpected token?

Comment: Did you change all of your JavaScript to be 100% browser compatible? Part of the value of Babel is allowing one to use current JavaScript standards without the need to worry about that (for the most part).